# Adding class to elements in a loop

Tags: javascript

I tried to come up with an idea for a carousel of elements that would change after clicking a button by changing their class, but the code doesn't want to run. This is where I landed:

```
var actionNeeded;
var option;

function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function slideChanger(option){
    var slides = [0, 1, 2, 3];

    switch(option) {
        case 1: actionNeeded = 'nextSlide';
        case 2: actionNeeded = 'prevSlide';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        $('slide-' + i).setAttribute('class', actionNeeded);
    }
}

window.onload == function(){
    $('nextArr').addEventListener('click', slideChanger(2), false);
    $('prevArr').addEventListener('click', slideChanger(1), false);
}
```

Where's the problem?

Comment: case 1: actionNeeded = 'nextSlide'; should be case 1: actionNeeded = 'nextSlide'; break;

Comment: Assign a function (as event handler), not its result. As a sidenote, I really fail to see why can't `slideChanger` decide what to do next based on its context, without any params to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// var option removed, is not needed
// var actionNeeded moved into function slideChanger, only needed there

function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function slideChanger(){
    var slides = [0, 1, 2, 3], actionNeeded;

    // keyword 'this' refers to the element on which this function is called
    // if #nextArr has called, 'this' is #nextArr, otherwise 'this' will be #prevArr
    // so we look for the id-attribute of 'this'
    if (this.id == 'nextArr') actionNeeded = 'prevSlide';
    else if (this.id == 'prevArr') actionNeeded = 'nextSlide';

    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        $('slide-' + i).setAttribute('class', actionNeeded);
    }
}

// in the listener you have to **point to** your function by its name
// if you set slideChanger(), you **execute** it and get only the result
window.onload = function(){
    $('nextArr').addEventListener('click', slideChanger, false);
    $('prevArr').addEventListener('click', slideChanger, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your function doesn't work because you don't assign it you just checking it with windows.onload why are you using `==`.That's a relay bad mistake you should use `=` instead of `==`  you know that `==` is for checking not assigning so you have to use `=`

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('nextArr').addEventListener('click', slideChanger(2), false);
    $('prevArr').addEventListener('click', slideChanger(1), false);
}
```

Comment: This is only one part of the problem.